# Existing shower/tub install is missing insulation in corner

Tags: insulation

I have a 1997 builder grade house with a 2nd story jack and Jill that’s the hottest/coldest room in the house despite the duct being directly under the air handler in the attic.
It butts up against the crawl space above the garage and an exterior wall so I have 3 insulation problems:

1. In the attic I saw bare drywall above the bathroom. I addressed this with some blown in insulation.
2. I’m relatively confident the ceiling of my garage isn’t filled so the floor of the bathroom isn’t insulated. I haven’t addressed this yet.
3. While there is insulation between the crawl space and bathroom and for sections of the exterior wall, It stops where the tub corner is.

So basically I have 2 studs-worth of the tub corner that’s not insulated both at the crawl space (1 in image) and against the exterior wall 2 in image).
I have insulation roll and I filled the gaps between tub and crawl space, but I can’t reach the exterior wall gaps.
What are my options to fill that space, how much heat/cold an I losing and how much energy do you think I’m losing in that section?

[image: Image here.]

Comment: Only touching one part: if your air sealing on the related parts (top and bottom plates) is good, you might be losing less energy than you think. Good luck getting this fixed up. Also I fixed your image link. Charge your phone battery. :)